# Is it correct to write $(a,b,c) < d$?

Tags: notation, article-writing

I want to say that the scalars $a$, $b$, and $c$ are all smaller than $d$. 
Is it mathematically correct if I write it like $$(a,b,c) < d?$$

Comment: That looks a bit strange. Without providing context, $(a,b,c)$ would generally be interpreted as a tuple, a vector, an element of $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Comment: I would just write $a,b,c<d$. In fact, in the context of writing $(a,b,c)<d$, some would interpret this as meaning $\gcd(a,b,c)<d$.

Comment: drop the parens, like dave said

Comment: Math isn't a programming language; anything that makes the meaning clear to the reader is fine. Parentheses usually aren't used for grouping like that, though (as opposed to indicating a vector, gcd, etc.). It would be clearer to write "$a, b, c < d$" or "each $a, b, c < d$." (If you're working with $a_1, a_2, a_3$ instead, you could also write something like "$a_i < d$ for each $i$.")

Comment: @anomaly Or to make it more cumbersome: $x < d$ for all $x \in \{a,b,c\}$. I wonder what the most verbose way someone could come up with is. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to write it is $a,b,c<d$. Since $(a,b,c)$ is a three-dimensional vector, and there is no canonical way to order vectors—let alone compare vectors with scalars—the notation $(a,b,c)<d$ makes no sense. However, if the elements of a finite set $A$ are orderable, it makes sense to write $\max A<d$ or $\max\{a,b,c\}<d$, where $A=\{a,b,c\}$.

Answer (score 2):

As it is just notation, there is no correct or incorrect. It is not common, I would say. You could use $\max(a,b,c) < d$ to avoid ambiguities.